# php quotes in html generates wrong code

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple code in html (image 1). The code is in the image i uploaded. When i open/run the file in Google chrome or Mozilla it generates wrong code. I tried to 'inspect element in Google Chrome and the code shown is in image 2. It messes up all the code because it generates it like a comment quote.

Why is this happening? Why the quote is transformed into a comment quote?

[image]

Comment: is the file extension `.php`?

Comment: yes. i also tried .html
I have done some projects in the University i have never come up with this problem before.

Comment: To code in php the extensions has to be `.php`. Second, the php file has to go through a webserver like IIS or Apache. Which will read the php file and return to you a nice html markup.

Comment: PHP code should never ever be seen by the browser to begin with. Why is your server not executing the PHP code? You're barking up the wrong tree to solve this problem.

Comment: Or perhaps more to the point, you are using a server, aren't you?

Comment: Or more to the point: what does the URL for the page look like exactly?

Comment: no i am not using a server. Why this simple code cannot be parsed correctly?

Comment: Because PHP **must be executed on a server!** It doesn't work in browsers.

Comment: View the source, not the DOM. What does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the PHP is not being parsed, and the PHP tags are being treated by the browser as comments.

Are you sure that your code is contained within a .php file and that PHP is installed and running on your server?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have written php(.php) code in html(.html) file. Confirm your file type

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not configured properly or XAMPP , WAMPP is not installed properly or the remote server has issue or you are running it directly from a file.So:

1-Check Apache if it is parsing PHP.

2-Check if PHP is installed.

3-Check if apache configured ports are free.

4-Ask for support in your contro panel of your hosting providers(if it is on a remote server).

5-Don't double click the PHP file.

6-Check the file extension.

7-Check your .htaccess file(if you have one).

8-Check PHP logs.

This should help you.

Answer (score -1):

For my php I usually use something like this if you only want to out put text.

```
    <?php
      echo "<p>Hello world</p>";
    ?>
```

Now if you have a variable you will need to do it this way

```
    <?php
      echo "<p>Hello".$myname.", welcome to my world.</p>";
    ?>
```

Now if you need something in a quote inside the echo statement you should do something like this

```
    <?php
      echo "<p>'Hello world'</p>";
    ?>
```

Comment: the problem is that when i open the file in the Google chrome or Mozilla the php code is been altered into a comment quote for html. And i don't know why this is keep happening.

Comment: What does you original code look like? does it look like something I posted above?

Comment: @PantelisGeorgiades the php file should not be opened on your local computer by a browser. It needs to be parsed by a web server like IIS or Apache.

Comment: I actually open it on my localhost I have WAMP running most of the time so if you are opening it on your local machine without a server running that could also be causing a problem.

Comment: @puddleJumper ok, so the problem is that i am trying to run it on my computer instead on a web server?

Comment: @Pantelis You can run it "on your computer", but that computer needs to have a web server running that parses PHP and you need to access your files through that web server, not by double clicking the file.

Comment: Ok yea first couple times I ran mine I forgot to turn on my server and got some weird errors. Now that I have WAMP I don't even turn it off most of the time is why it didn't occur to me that you may not have one.